# adding multiple input fileds dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

I need to add new input field when button is pressed. I can do it using Anggular ng-repeat and array pushing.

But I have 6-7 inputs where I have to do this. It seems to me that I have to create multiple addInput functions and use ng-repeat in every one of the input fileds. It's just too much hassle.

Obviously, there's a smarter way to do this? I think custom directives might give me the solution but I have never used them. So need some guidelines to solve this.

Pleas advise. thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of any other way besides having an array of inputs and pushing it. This is one ng-repeat though - your repeat inputs in your array of inputs. When you need a new input, you push to that array. I don't think directives will help you here, though you could ng-repeat directives (but that won't be any easier).

Comment: okay. thanks though. :)